When was the first holy day of obligation instituted?
When did the concept of a holy day of obligation become part of the Catholic Churches code?
It would be particularly helpful to include:

any early church fathers who argued missing Sunday Mass could be sinful
a distinction if the holy day of obligation was originally just for days like Easter, but then was later expanded to Sundays (dating helpful here)


Do you mean any day that assisting at Mass was obligated or to distinguish Sundays from other feasts? We tend to use the term "holy day of obligation" more so for days besides the regular Sunday. Sunday obligation is almost certainly ancient/Apostolic.

Good question! (Colossians 2:6-23) KJV

@eques I’m specifically referring to the idea that not attending mass on a given day constitutes a sin. That can either be Sunday or a feast day like the assumption of the Virgin Mary (which need not fall on a Sunday)

I suppose the follow-up is what does "part of the Catholic Churches code" mean. Do you mean when it first became part of law for the entire Church or when it first was taught by anyone officially?

@eques It could be both
